# Debug c++ no Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Instalei o Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express. Criei um projeto utilizando Win32 Console Application, adicionei um New Iten C++ File(.cpp) a esse projeto, mas na hora de rodar aparece o erro:

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode desabilitar a linkagem incremental para contornar o problema ou pode atualizar para uma versão mais moderna...

```
Project Properties 
   -> Configuration Properties 
       -> Linker (General) 
          -> Enable Incremental Linking -> "No (/INCREMENTAL:NO)"
```

Comment: Já fiz isso mas não ta rodando,

Comment: antes aparecia o erro q coloquei na pergunta agora que fiz isso não aparece o erro, mas também não roda, a tela do console aparece e some  rápido

Comment: está aparecendo isso: The program '[736] Aula1.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: é meu primeiro programa em c++, quero q escreva "hello word"

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
 
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{     
    printf("Hello Word");    
    return 0; 
}

Comment: está assim: #include <stdio.h>
 
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{     
    printf("Hello Word");   
 int espera; 
 cin >> espera;
    return 0; 
}

Comment: mas aparece isso: The program '[3924] Aula1.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: fiz isso: #include <stdio.h>
 
main()
{
 char user[10];
 printf("Digite o nome do usuario: ");
 scanf("%s", &user);
}

Comment: e mostra isso: 'Aula1.exe': Loaded 'D:\Users\Sara\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Aula1\Debug\Aula1.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Aula1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Aula1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Aula1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Aula1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
The program '[1548] Aula1.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Pode adicionar um breakpoint antes do return 0... ao iniciar o debug ele deve parar lá...